# how to push submodules with multiple accounts correctly

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project that contains a submodule. Both the project and the submodule are cloned through ssh authentication, using different accounts. The project's structure is the following:

```
tests          <- project root
|- tstsub      <- submodule root
|- <project's files>
|- .gitmodules
```

This is my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
#activehacker account
Host github.com-matteoappfarmer
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_matteoappfarmer
    ServerAliveInterval 60

#activehacker account
Host github.com-matteoappfarmer+gist
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_matteoappfarmer+gist
    ServerAliveInterval 60

#activehacker account
Host github.com-bertamini.matteo
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bertamini.matteo
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

and these are the commands I've used to set my project up:

1. cloning my project

   ```
   git clone git@github.com-bertamini.matteo:bertuz/bertuzFox.git tests
   ```
2. adding a submodule (by entering in tests)

   ```
   git submodule add git@github.com-bertamini.matteo:bertuz/bertuzFox.git tstsub
   ```
3. Ok, let's check that everything is in order in our new .gitmodules

   ```
   [submodule "tstsub"]
       path = tstsub
       url = git@github.com-bertamini.matteo:bertuz/bertuzFox.git
   ```

`github.com-bertamini.matteo`seems to be the right thing for authenticating properly. Ok, let's go on.

4. Entering in tstsub, creating and adding a file, commit it (remember we are in the submodule now). Then checking if git has everything set properly

   ```
   MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo:tstsub matteo$ git status
   On branch master
   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

       modified:   README.md
   ```
5. Alright! Let's try to push our submodule then:

   ```
   MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo:tstsub matteo$ git push
   ERROR: Permission to bertuz/bertuzFox.git denied to bertuz-gist.
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
   ```

so, it seems we have a problem with the submodule and multiple ssh authentications. It says "persmission denied to bertuz-gist". I think git is not using the submodule's auth information it should use, but the project's ones. How could I change and set this properly in order to push my submodule modifications?

Comment: Do you have different config file (user/email) per submodule or do you use the same "global" config for them all?

Comment: I set `git config user.email "bertamini.matteo@gmail.com"` and `git config user.name "git"` in the `tstsub`dir. That's the email I used for generating the public key named `github.com-bertamini.matteo`

Comment: So each of your submodule has the right configuration. you can verify it by creating a dummy branch, commit to it and view the owner. once you done delete the branch. in this way you can verify that the configuration is correct.

Comment: If I run git log in the tstsub subdir I get a different history from the parent dir, which is fine I guess. I've tried to create a new branch and commit to it and I get this: Author: git <bertamini.matteo@gmail.com>Author: git <bertamini.matteo@gmail.com> I guess it is more than fine! But I'm still experiencing problems by pushing my submodule's master branch.